# Ordenação múltiplas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

A tabela de vendas tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
id_venda | nome_cliente | data_venda | data_agendamento | data_cancelamento | data_ligacao
```

Onde os campos "data" são todos datetime.
Gostaria de ordenar de acordo com a ultima movimentação ocorrida.
Mas a venda terá preenchida mais de um campo.
Terá data de ligacao, data de agendamento e data de cancelamento por exemplo, sendo que a ultima coisa que ocorreu foi o cancelamento.

Tentei assim mas sem sucesso:

```
 select * from vendas order by data_venda desc, data_agendamento desc,
 data_cancelamento desc, data_ligacao desc;
```

Mas ordena pelo primeiro campo, ignorando os restantes.
Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Tenta utilizar um `max(data_*)` para considerar apenas a data mais recente de cada registro

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele tem que usar a cláusula greatest na realidade. Só não sei se suporta mais de 2 colunas

Comment: Esses campos de datas estão todos preenchidos e alguns estão com NULL ou Em Branco ?

Comment: @RobertoValentim Sim, alguns nulos outros preenchidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM vendas
 ORDER BY GREATEST(data_venda, data_agendamento, data_cancelamento, data_ligacao);
```

> [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)
>
> With two or more arguments, returns the largest (maximum-valued) argument.

Ou em tradução livre:

> Com dois ou mais argumentos, retorna o maior (máximo-valor) argumento.